# C#: Is this possible to convert 24hrs format string Datetime to 12hrs AM/PM dateformat (again in string only)

Tags: c#

I have a date/time return from a C# method is in string,

```
string dateTime = "2018-6-18 20:50:35"
```

Now I would like to convert this into another string representation like,

```
string convertDT = "2018-6-18 08:50:35 PM"
```

Is this possible?

Seems like I can do something like,

```
var formattedTime = dateTime.ToString("h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but not working. Suggestion please!

Comment: Parse the string into a DateTime, then call ToString() on that object in the format you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just parse the string into a new DateTime object and then call `ToString()` with the right formats:

```
string dateTime = "2018-6-18 20:50:35";
DateTime parsedDateTime;
if(DateTime.TryParse(dateTime, out parsedDateTime))
{
    return parsedDateTime.ToString("yyyy-M-d hh:mm tt");
}
```

The benefit of my answer is that it contains validation (`DateTime.TryParse()`), it results in a couple extra lines of code but you can now accept all input and not worry about an exception being thrown.

Even better would be to refactor this logic into its own method that you can re-use:

```
public static bool TryChangeDateTimeFormat(string inputDateString, string outputFormat, out string outputDateString)
{
    DateTime parsedDateTime;
    if(DateTime.TryParse(inputDateString, out parsedDateTime))
    {
        outputDateString = parsedDateTime.ToString(outputFormat);
        return true;
    }
    outputDateString = string.Empty;
    return false;
}
```

This returns a bool of whether or not the conversion was successful and the `out` variable will be modified depending on the result.

Fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/czxCha)

Answer (score 1):

Without adding any validation,

```
var string24h = "2018-6-18 20:50:35";
var dateTime = DateTime.Parse(string24h);
var formattedTime = dateTime.ToString("h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [DateTime.ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) and then `ToString`

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can use the `DateTime` class to parse the original string and then output a differently formatted string for the same date:

```
string result = DateTime.Parse(dateTime).ToString("h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var dateTime = "2018-6-18 20:50:35";
var dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTime);
var amPmDateTime = dt.ToString(@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

To give you exactly your format you would use

```
string convertDT = DateTime.Parse(dateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss tt");
```

You can change the format between the quotes however you would like. For example yyyy/MM/dd or something. Just remember MM is 2 spots for months and mm is 2 spots for minutes.

So if you put

```
string convertDT = DateTime.Parse(dateTime).ToString("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss tt");
```

You are going to get year - minutes - days.